# Сортировка массива по алфавитном порядке, без исползоваия метод sort(можно исползовать for, if else, compare)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сортировка

string[] month = new string[]
{
"January",
"February",
"March",
"April",
"May",
"June",
"July",
"August",
"September",
"October",
"November",
"December"
};

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Используйте `OrderBy` + `ToArray`. _Ваш К. О._

Comment: [Самая простая сортировка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Comment: @aepot сначала переобразаватъ string в char

Comment: @VladD OrderBy тоже нельзя исползоватъ

Comment: `сначала переобразаватъ string в char` - зачем? у строки есть метод `s1.CompareTo(s2)`, он возвращает -1, 0 или 1 в зависимости от того, левая строка меньше, равна или больше. Строки сравниваются как раз в алфавитном порядке. [`IComparable<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @aepot только через массив, а не обобщений. ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ?

Comment: Читать методичку и пересматривать лекцию/вебминар/что-там-еще-бывает. Вы сейчас просто написал комментарий, никак не имеющий отношение к тому, что я написал. Я не предлагал вам никаких обобщений. А вы, получается, даже не открыли ссылку, которую я вам дал в комментарии выше.

Answer (score 1):

В принципе все очень просто. Есть два варианта решения данной задачи.

1. Можно сравнить строки. public static int Compare (string? strA, string? strB); Соответственно сортируем исходя из данного метода (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=net-5.0)
2. Можно заморочиться чуть побольше и сравнивать символы public int CompareTo (char value);
   (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.char.compareto?view=net-5.0)

Все, что осталось сделать это выбрать алгоритм сортировки. (https://programm.top/c-sharp/algorithm/array-sort/bubble-sort/). Я реализовал самое простое, сортировку пузырьком.

Чтобы совсем не решать за Вас задачу, её отладкой не занимался и она содержит неточности. Так, что перебор вариантов и нахождение ошибок, возложу на плечи студента, а сам принцип в программе прослеживается.

```
    using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Sort {
  // Start Point.
  static void Main() {
    var months = new string[] { "aa", "aaa", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
    
    // Variables for sort.
    var sortedByLibrary = months.Select(x => x).ToArray();
    var sortedByHand = months.Select(x => x).ToArray();
    
    // Sort By Library.
    Array.Sort(sortedByLibrary);

    // Sort By Hand.
    BubbleSort(sortedByHand);
    
    // Output.
    Console.WriteLine( sortedByLibrary.SequenceEqual(sortedByHand) ? "OK" : "Error");
    Console.WriteLine("Input array: "  + string.Join(", ", months));
    Console.WriteLine("Library sorted array: "  + string.Join(", ", sortedByLibrary));
    Console.WriteLine("Hand sorted array: "  + string.Join(", ", sortedByHand));
  }
  
  // Bubble sort for our Massive.
  private static void BubbleSort(string[] array)
  {
    var len = array.Length;
    for (var i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < len - i; j++)
        {
            // If Char Compare.
            //if(CompareWords(array[j], array[j + 1]))
            //{
            //    Swap(ref array[j], ref array[j + 1]);
            //}
            
            // If Strings Compare.
            if(String.Compare(array[j], array[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                Swap(ref array[j], ref array[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
  }
  
  private static bool CompareWords(string word1, string word2)
  {
    // Input params.
    var word1CharArray = word1.ToCharArray();
    var word2CharArray = word2.ToCharArray();
    var word1CharArrayLen = word1CharArray.Length;
    var word2CharArrayLen = word2CharArray.Length;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < word1CharArrayLen; i++)
    {
        if(i <= word2CharArrayLen)
        {
            if(word1CharArray[i].CompareTo(word2CharArray[i]) < 0)
            {
                return false; 
            }
            else if(word1CharArray[i].CompareTo(word2CharArray[i]) > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
  
  // Swap Elements.
  static void Swap(ref string element1, ref string element2)
  {
    var temp = element1;
    element1 = element2;
    element2 = temp;
  }
}
```